# Loops through an array of pages in wordpress

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, loops

I came across this function for wordpress. It displays a link to navigate through pages.

If page is A, then next page is B

If page is B, then next page is C and previous page is A

If page is C, then previous page is B

```
function siblings($link) {
  global $post;
  $siblings = get_pages('child_of='.$post->post_parent.'&parent='.$post->post_parent);
  foreach ($siblings as $key=>$sibling){
    if ($post->ID == $sibling->ID){
        $ID = $key;
    }
}
$closest = array('before'=>get_permalink($siblings[$ID-1]->ID),'after'=>get_permalink($siblings[$ID+1]->ID));

if ($link == 'before' || $link == 'after') { 
    echo $closest[$link]; }
else { 
    return $closest; }
}
```

However, when it reaches C, the "next" link is still C. And when the page is A, the "previous" link is still A.

How to modify it so when it's A, the "previous" link is C, and when it's C, the "next" link is A ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to rewrite this in the following way, which should do what you want:

```
$last_item = end( $siblings );

$before = ( $ID-1 > 0 ) ? get_permalink( $siblings[$ID-1]->ID ) : get_permalink( $last_item->ID );
$after = ( $ID+1 < count( $siblings ) )  ? get_permalink( $siblings[$ID+1]->ID ) : $siblings[0]->ID;

$closest = array( 'before' => $before, 'after' => $after );
```

Where ? is the [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary).

Comment: $closest = ... (as you should be able to figure out by careful examination!)